Как узнать, в каком хроме выполняется расширение?
Я хочу из расширения узнать, как называется хромиумный браузер, в котором оно исполняется, например Comodo Dragon, Avast Browser, Yandex Browser, Google Chrome, MS Edge и т. д. Ну или хотя бы часть названия - например, пойдёт просто comodo или просто dragon. Как его получить?
В userAgent подобных данных нет, например, Comodo Dragon не упоминает ни comodo, ни dragon:

Думал как-то достать из chrome://version, но через fetch она недоступна:


похоже такое только для firefox есть

Для сhrome-образных попробуйте — navigator.userAgentData.brands +  MDN

@stylok, работает в Авасте, Xроме, ЯБ и Edge. Но не работает в Драконе.

@stylok, ответ напишешь? Но, наверное, галочку ставить не буду... Я думал именно через возможности расширения как-то докопаться - мне кажется, это должно быть точнее, чем способами, которые можно с обычной страницы использовать.

Мне нечего дополнить к уже имеющимся текстам и примерам там. Понятия не имею зачем вам это нужно и для чего такие сложности, но у меня нет желания скачивать, устанавливать и экспериментировать с ненужными мне браузерами. Лично у меня в расширениях и сейчас стоит проверка на navigator.userAgent.includes('Chrome'). Всё что не Chromium — Gecko. И мне этого хватает.

@stylok, я для себя делаю и пользуюсь несколькими браузерами. Мне надо браузер в название скачиваемого файла вписать, но при этом хочу подключить в них одну папку с расширением, а не отдельное под каждый браузер.

Тогда есть подозрение, что разработчики Дракона в принципе поленились добавить какие-либо опознавательные знаки в своём форке

@andreymal, ну или специально маскируются - типа "безопасный" же. Но по сути userAgentData - это апи для сайтов - обычно расширениям дают больше возможностей, чем сайтам.
